# Firebase FCM token and customized message to each user

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a requirement in which I need to send push notification to each and every user every morning. But each user will get customized notification message according to their progress.

I have written a cloud function that sends same message to every user as it sends to topic. I have below questions regarding firebase and notifications.

1. Does firebase stores the FCM token automatically? Right now I am storing the FCM token manually into Firestore once user registers.
2. If firebase stores the FCM token automatically then how can I retrieve them?
3. As I am sending customized message to each user I am not able to use topics to send customized notification to each user. What is the other way to send notification to single user at a time?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate (?) of [Best practices for storing ID tokens and sending web push notifications using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46091412/4625829)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It doesn't. [It's the developer's responsibility to store the tokens as they need them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41995729/4625829). So what you're currently doing is the right way to go.
2. See 1.
3. There is no other way around this one. If each user is to receive a unique message, then you'd have to send a separate request for each.

Comment: With all that said, please *avoid* having multiple questions in a single post. Cheers!